# Special subnumbering for equation

Tags: equations, numbering

I would like to display two seperate equations with the same generated number and then the letter 'a' added to the first and the letter 'b' to the second.

```
Some text.  
  x=y                       (2a)  
Some text.  
  y=z                       (2b)  
Some text.
```

Then, later on, I will have to reference (2a) and (2b).

Comment: Also, the `amsmath` package provides `\intertext` for placing text between adjacent equations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`amsmath` package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath?lang=en) provides the `subequations` environment exactly for that purpose. Just enclosed the whole block in `\begin{subequations} ... \end{subequations}`. See [section 3.11.3 of the documentation](http://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/required/amsmath/amsldoc.pdf) for more details.

Comment: This works perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

A combination of `subequations` and `\intertext`, employed in the right combination.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\noindent some text
\begin{subequations}
\begin{gather}
  x = y\\
\intertext{some text}
  x = y
\end{gather}
\end{subequations}
some text
\end{document}
```

[image]

If the intertext is very short, one can compress the vertical space by using the `\shortintertext` macro from the `mathtools` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\begin{document}
\noindent some text
\begin{subequations}
\begin{gather}
  x = y\\
\shortintertext{some text}
  x = y
\end{gather}
\end{subequations}
some text
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great answer, I will use it in the future. For now, I will user the other answer.